# Random Forest for very large Dataset

Tags: c++, r, random-forest

I have a dataset with **10 billion** samples (10^10) with 100 features (and yes, I also have the labels). I'd like to train a random forest for classification.

Is it possible to train like 10000 decision trees on randomly sampled subsets (one after another) and combine these trees to one forest? If Yes, how?

Comment: I am not a statistics expert, but if you have 1) a small number of features like you do here, 2) a faster converging algorithm like a DTree instead of, say, a deep net, isn't *8 orders of magnitude* of samples more than feature space overkill for an algorithm without good high-order feature detection (like a net)? Please educate me :)

Comment: Thank you. I think that should depend on the data itself. But since you question my classifier choice, do you have any idea how to tackle this amount of data with any classifier?

Comment: what size on disk is this dataset? Classifier selection is extremely complicated, but I was looking at it from a different perspective: with a DTree, you can generally afford to use fewer observations than with a complex net structure. So sampling down your data by 100 or so. But again, as you said, your data completely determines your ML problem - what is its schema? If it has low frequency seasonality, you may need all 10b samples, etc... In a classification prob like this though, i think you can probably get away with fewer examples

Comment: btw i think posting this in http://stats.stackexchange.com/ is a better idea - doesn't seem to be any C++ specific question here.